# Here I prove every free group is free abelian. Where is the mistake?

Tags: group-theory, fake-proofs, free-groups, free-abelian-group

Let $F$ be free over $X$. Then for any group $G$ and any $\alpha: X \to G$ there is a homomorphism $\beta: F \to G$ such that $\alpha = \beta|X$. Alright. Now, in particular, when $G$ is abelian $F$ satisfies the definition of free abelian group. That is, if a group $F$ is free then $F$ is free abelian. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Part of the definition of a free abelian group is that the group is abelian (not only are the target groups $G$ in the universal property restricted to abelian groups, but $F$ itself is required to be abelian).  So your proof shows that if $F$ is a free group on a set $X$ *and* $F$ happens to be abelian, then $F$ is also a free abelian group on $X$.  But $F$ may not be abelian (and in fact is not if $X$ has more than one element).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I just solved an exercise that says that if F is free then F is abelian if and only if F is infinite cyclic. As Z(F) is trivial for rank > 1, then the only way for F to be abelian is that the rank be 1.